# Jest fails even though array does contain the expected element, why

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

In my jest test case, I would like to verify the json contains certain element. Following is what I tried.

My Json data is:

```
{"name":"foo","age": 20,"otherInfo":"http://example.com"}
```

I created a parser to get an array of strings out from json object:

```
// a parser function for transforming json object to string[]
const parseJsonElements = (jsonData: object) =>
  JSON.stringify(jsonData).replace(/[{}]/g, '').split(',');

// parse my json data
const elements = parseJsonElements(myJsonDataObj);

// verify elements contains json element
expect(elements).toContain(`"otherInfo":"http://example.com"`);
```

Above jest run fails with error:

```
Expected value: "\"otherInfo\":\"http://example.com\""
Received array: ["\"name\":\"foo\"","\"age\":\"20\"","\"otherInfo\":\"http://example.com\""]
```

But it looks like the received array does contain that element. Why Jest fails?

**========= update =======**

Tried `expect(jsonData).toHaveProperty("otherInfo", "http://example.com")`, it works. But what if I want to verify nested element exists? For example:

my json data:

```
{"name":"foo","age": 20,"otherInfo":{"type":"homepage", "url":"http://example.com"}}
```

Then, `expect(jsonData).toHaveProperty("url", "http://example.com")` still fail. Any suggestion for this nested json element check?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using just `expect(jsonData).toHaveProperty("otherInfo", "http://example.com")`?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that, btw is there a way to verify nested json element ?

Comment: Jest has [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect). Nested properties can be checked like `.toHaveProperty("otherInfo.url", "http://example.com")` or `.toHaveProperty(["otherInfo", "url"], "http://example.com")`. See [`.toHaveProperty()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavepropertykeypath-value). You can also check against another (possibly nested) object with [`.objectContaining()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectobjectcontainingobject).